# Node.js: Передача данных на клиент

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

### Ситуация

У меня есть `node.js` сервер на `express`. Мне нужно передать значение переменной на клиент и обработать эти данные с помощью сырого `js`.

### Проблема

Знаю про `websocket` (модуль `ws`), но он нужен для дуплексного соидинения. Пользуюсь `socket.io` но он нужен для передачи данных на несколко клиентов (broadcast).

### Вопрос

Как можно передать значение переменной на клиент? Есть ли какие встроенные способы передачи данных на клиент?

Comment: А почему не отдать JSON ?

Comment: Можете навести пример (не совсем понимаю о чем идет речь)?

Comment: @Maks Mihalchuk А что вам мешает при использовании socket.io передать данные только одному клиенту по уникальному id.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647348/send-message-to-specific-client-with-socket-io-and-node-js

Comment: @Bleser Согласен, можно. Но это все равно что купить смартфон только для того что бы пользоваться фонариком. Передачу данных одному клиенту можно сделать также на вебсокетах. Но я ищу способ попроще.

Comment: Ну, в express `res.json(ваша_переменная_в_виде_json)`, при обращении к странице ajax клиент получит в ответ json с переменной, а дальше работайте с ней. Как-то так.

Answer (score 5):

Сервер:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ "ключ" : "значение" }); 
});
```

Клиент:

```
const myInit = {
  method: 'get'
};

fetch('http://localhost:9000/test', myInit)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)// {"ключ":"значение"}
  });
```